# Using UIImage as a tag in a Grouped TableViewCell

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I am relatively new and I have this question where I would like to know to code in Xcode (without IB) a UIImage as icons (to function as tags) to a TableView cell. They would have to be able to be assigned to a particular data contained in a dynamic tableview. An analogy would be say:

[Image of a dog] assigned to a Golden Retriever,
[Image of a cat] assigned to a Siamese,
[Image of a dog] assigned to a Dalmatian, etc

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using UIImage as a tag is not possible because [tag](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW25) is an integer that you can use to identify view objects in your application .Since tag is an inherited property from UIView, you cannot use it with UIImage itself, but you can use it with UIImageView,
Set the tag on the imageView itself:

```
#define IMAGE_TAG_GREEN 50
#define IMAGE_TAG_RED   51

-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView*) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
  static NSString *CELL_ID = @"some_cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_ID];
  if(cell == nil) {
     //do setup here...
     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CELL_ID] autorelease];
     cell.imageView.tag = //some logic here...
  }
 if(cell.imageView.tag == IMAGE_TAG_GREEN) {
//...
  } else {
//...
  }
  return cell;

}
```